# ExtJS 4.2 - Ext.ux.Printer library/class does not work

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Good day. Sorry but I've stumbled upon a problem that I can't seem to figure out for the past couple of hours. I downloaded this [printing class](https://github.com/edspencer/Ext.ux.Printer) to be able to print a Form that I have in my web application. I copied the `Ext.ux.Printer` folder in my `scripts` folder inside `resources`. The file path looks like: `resources/scripts/Ext.ux.Printer` and the resources folder is on the same level as the `app` folder.

My Loader looks like:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        'Ext.ux.Printer': 'resources/scripts/Ext.ux.Printer/Printer'
    }
});
```

And the Application looks like:

```
Ext.application({

    requires: [
        'Ext.Loader',
        'Ext.layout.container.Absolute',
        'resources.scripts.Notification',
        'Ext.layout.container.Column',
        'Ext.ux.Printer.Printer'
    ], //models, views, controllers, follow after
```

and I try to use it in my code as such:

```
Ext.ux.Printer.print(form);
```

However, I am given an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Printer' of undefined` whenever I try to execute the line of code above.

Can anyone help me? I'm a beginner in ExtJS4 and I'm just trying to follow examples I see around the internet - it is possible that I tried to appropriate my code incorrectly with something I saw online.

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

**UPDATE 1**

Upon discussion with Guilherme Lopes below we did the following steps:

1. Import the js files by adding it as a js resource in Sencha Architect. Make sure that the file path is correct.
2. Check the `includeAfterAppJS` checkbox. Due to a bug in Architect, sometimes the JS Files are added in before the ExtJS.
3. Open `index.html`use `ext-all.js` instead of `ext-dev.js`. Note that Sencha Architect overwrites/resets this file every time you save your project. A quick fix is to go to project settings and uncheck updating index.html.
4. Try `Ext.ux.Print.print(form);`

Answer (score 0):

By the developer instructions, you should import the script files using your main html document, the same way you do with ExtJS classes (if you are not using the bootstrap).

These lines should be added after you import the ExtJS library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Printer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="renderers/Base.js"></script>

The library currently comes with renderers for Ext.grid.GridPanel, and Ext.tree.ColumnTree.
These can be included as required:
<script type="text/javascript" src="renderers/GridPanel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="renderers/ColumnTree.js"></script>
```

And your calls to Ext.ux.Printer should start working.

If you are using Architect, add your external JS files clicking on: + => Resources => JS Resource
And then change the URL to the path you need (do this for every file you wish to add)
* I would just uncheck the x-compile and x-bootstrap

[image: Adding resource]
[image: Changing Settings]

Comment: Upon checking the generated `index.html` file, the bootstrap is being used. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to touch this file.

Comment: Are you using Architect?

Comment: Yes. Sencha Architect 3.1

Comment: I've added instructions for Architect

Comment: I'm assuming that I should remove the code I placed in the `Loader`?

Comment: I am getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined ` in all the .js files I added, pointing to `Ext.ux.Printer` or Ext.ux.classname.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64582/discussion-between-guilherme-lopes-and-razgriz).